# Comparing CSV properties with Compare-Object

Tags: powershell, compare

I'm looking to compare 2 CSV files which have hostnames and then lots of properties. Here I'm interested in 2 of these additional lets call them "room" and "tag". I'm running

```
Compare-Object $refCsv $difCsv -Property hostname, room, tag
```

This is supposed to be finding all matching hostnames in my CSVs where either room or tag differ. In result however I get hostname, room, tag and  sideindicator where instead of sideindicator I'd rather see the value. How can this be done?

Comment: use the `-PassThru` parameter to get all properties from the Ref side.

Comment: What LotPings said. If you want to remove the automatically included side-indicator from that output use something like `... | Select-Object -Property * -Exclude SideIndicator`.

Comment: But this would only remove the side indicator not replace it with the values I'd need e.g. $sideindicator = $difCsv.room althoug this would display all room values rather than the one corresponding to the particular hostname.